# Standard cutting propagation for all hanger/climbers houseplants?

Tags: propagation, cuttings

I've seen this video on youtube,

[Propagation of Aeschinanthus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9M6dcku8qE&t=86s)

The idea is to cut the vine into segments, each with one leaf (for monocots) or two leaves (for eudicots), planting the cuttings in the soil with just the leaves sticking out.

Assuming my plants can be propagated by cuttings, would this method work for all cuttings? Do some plants require other factors, such as keeping the growth tip, using a longer segment, or a longer internode?

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to check out propagation techniques for particular plants before trying - some (like Epipremnum or Tradescantia) are really easy and will root quite readily in a bottle of water on a windowsill, so trying to stick to a single method for all plants may be neither appropriate  nor necessary.